# The database file is larger than the configured maximum database size. what does this mean?

Tags: c#, sql, database

HI i get this exception sometimes while updating my sql compact database.
error is as follows:

```
2/6/2017 11:06:08 AM ERROR IN SavePacket(EnergyMeter_Grid e) data into file
 System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbUpdateException: An error occurred while updating the entries. See the inner exception for details. ---> System.Data.Entity.Core.UpdateException: An error occurred while updating the entries. See the inner exception for details. ---> System.Data.SqlServerCe.SqlCeException: The database file is larger than the configured maximum database size. This setting takes effect on the first concurrent database connection only. [ Required Max Database Size (in MB; 0 if unknown) = 21 ]
   at System.Data.SqlServerCe.SqlCeCommand.ProcessResults(Int32 hr)
   at System.Data.SqlServerCe.SqlCeCommand.ExecuteCommandText(IntPtr& pCursor, Boolean& isBaseTableCursor)
   at System.Data.SqlServerCe.SqlCeCommand.ExecuteCommand(CommandBehavior behavior, String method, ResultSetOptions options)
   at System.Data.SqlServerCe.SqlCeCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
   at System.Data.Entity.SqlServerCompact.SqlCeMultiCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
   at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.InternalDispatcher`1.Dispatch[TTarget,TInterceptionContext,TResult](TTarget target, Func`3 operation, TInterceptionContext interceptionContext, Action`3 executing, Action`3 executed)
   at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.DbCommandDispatcher.NonQuery(DbCommand command, DbCommandInterceptionContext interceptionContext)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Mapping.Update.Internal.DynamicUpdateCommand.Execute(Dictionary`2 identifierValues, List`1 generatedValues)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Mapping.Update.Internal.UpdateTranslator.Update()
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Mapping.Update.Internal.UpdateTranslator.Update()
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.ExecuteInTransaction[T](Func`1 func, IDbExecutionStrategy executionStrategy, Boolean startLocalTransaction, Boolean releaseConnectionOnSuccess)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.SaveChangesToStore(SaveOptions options, IDbExecutionStrategy executionStrategy, Boolean startLocalTransaction)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.SaveChangesInternal(SaveOptions options, Boolean executeInExistingTransaction)
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.SaveChanges()
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.SaveChanges()
   at ILS.DB.DbUpdateLoop.SavePacket(EnergyMeter_Grid e)
```

I know this is probably cause of size, cause the other days i manually gave the size of my db as 4 gb.

```
     using (var context = Context.Create("C:\\XSR_BIB_V2\\XSR_BIB_V2_DATABASE.sdf", "", 4091))
                    {
                        if (DbUpdateLoop.context.Database.Connection.State == System.Data.ConnectionState.Closed)
                            DbUpdateLoop.context.Database.Connection.Open();
}
```

this exception doesn't effect much of my functionality but i am curious is to what might be wrong. this exception normally happens at this spot called `SavePacket(EnergyMeter_Grid e)`    as you can see from the exception log above.

savePacket(energyMeter grid e) code::::

```
if (DbUpdateLoop.context.Database.Connection.State == System.Data.ConnectionState.Closed)
                {
                    DbUpdateLoop.context.Database.Connection.Open();
                }

                if (e == null)
                    throw new ArgumentNullException("Energy Meter Packet");
                EnergyMeter_Grid eInfo = new EnergyMeter_Grid(e.MeterId, e.KW, e.KWh, e.EId);
                using (context.Database.BeginTransaction())
                {
                    context.EnergyMeter_GridTbl.Add(eInfo);
                }
                context.SaveChanges();
```

explanation of code: its simple, all i am doing is opening a context and doing transcation of energyMeter_gridtable values as param into sql compact db and saving changes.

```
would love if someone one tell me why this error is happening and what should i do to resolve it??
```

Comment: did you configured your max db size

Comment: Yes i have to 4091-(4gb) to be exact.

Comment: Which SQL CE version you have used? Check this DB size parameter description first: http://blogs.msdn.com/sqlservercompact/archive/2007/06/13/the-story-of-max-database-size-connection-string-parameter.aspx, and try using size parameter in SDF connection string: `Data Source=[Database Name].sdf;Max Database Size=4096`

Comment: Hi version 4.0 i am using. whose limit is 4091. i should mention this above exception  i get  once in a while may be once in a day or so..

Comment: Have your actual DB size exceeded 4091 MB limit? Try using `Shrink` (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlserverce.sqlceengine.shrink.aspx) and `Compact` (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlserverce.sqlceengine.compact.aspx) to compress database size.

Comment: db has not exceeded its limit.